# Как пишут ботов для компьютерных игр?

Tags: бот

Видел на YouTube [видео](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=W4j7HC63cTs) в котором явно играет не человек, а бот. Как такое вообще возможно? Как можно написать бота, который будет с экрана "брать" элементы, расчитывать выгодные попадания, учитывать скорость? Как такие боты пишутся?

Comment: Почему сразу с экрана, можно влезть в машинный код игры и подменить там что-нибудь, например. Хотя игры типа Zuma наверно действительно нетрудно (относительно) обманывать несложными методами обработки изображений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Факт 1. Вы можете использовать WinApi чтобы посылать нажатия клавиш и щелчки/движения мышки в определённых координатах.
Факт 2. Вы можете свободно копаться в оперативной памяти чужих программ (используя более низкоуровневые языки), вы можете слушать соединение игры с игровым сервером: в котором все ключевые данные (положение игрока и соперников например) как-раз и передают регулярно.

Так с простым ботом ничего сложного - перехватываете нужные данные, например положение деревьев и игрока в компьютерной игре. Ваш некий алгоритм определяет какие клавиши надо жать в текущий момент времени, куда двигать мышку. Выполняете, и дальше по кругу.

Некоторое время назад зарабатывал на ботах для браузерных игр. Так вот лично мои боты были расширениями браузеров написанные только на JS. Плюс расширения в этом деле в том, что есть DOM дерево: то есть очень просто достать исчерпывающую информацию о мире игры. Также интересно то, что можно "командовать" окном игры, вызывая из расширения любые скрипты в пространстве окна, а ещё в пространстве расширения можно подключать прямо из JS dll библиотеки, например WinApi .

Answer (score 0):

В многих играх есть API для читов.
Бот может использовать его, или, например, обработку изображений.
В паре с этим вполне может использоваться виртуальное
нажатие клавиш. В Java это вполне реализуемо:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
...
public void pressKey(Robot instance, int key) {
    instance.keyPress(key);
}
public void releaseKey(Robot instance, int key) {
    instance.keyRelease(key);
}
```